# How to find entry point of a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the entry point of a spring boot application?

While going through a Spring Boot application code, all that it says is there is a code

```
public static void main having - SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)
```

Example - [SpringBoot2RestServiceApplication.java](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples/blob/master/spring-boot-2-rest-service-with-hateoas/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/springboot/rest/example/SpringBoot2RestServiceApplication.java) .

But how to get to know what is the entry point, just by going through the code. Earlier, if we go through `applicationContext.xml` - example - [applicationContext.xml](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples/blob/master/spring-boot-tutorial-basics/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml), we could understand the flow.

Is there any way, or maybe a standard to follow to make this understanding self-explanatory?

My question was more of understanding the flow of the application than finding the main class. One option could be separating configurations(@Configuration) to a separate class having multiple @Bean annotations, this would help in finding all bean wirings at one place. Is there a standard that large projects use to make code flow understandable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the OP is studying an existing Spring Boot application, and is asking how to locate any runner, such as Application Runners, Command Line Runners, MVC controllers, Rest controllers, etc.

I don't know if there is an easy way to locate those, unless they are grouped together in the original design.

It's a difficult problem to do programmatically, because threads can be launched outside of Spring, for example in a constructor or a @PostConstruct.

It would be nice though if there were IDE support to easily locate anything that gets launched by Spring Boot

Comment: Is there some good practices that projects could follow to design Spring boot applications where code can be more readable and understand the flow of the application. Like previously there used to be applicationContext.xml which provides the flow, similar kind of practices with annotation based application can follow.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to search for `@SpringBootApplication` in your code.

But, a guaranteed way to get this information would be to build the Spring Boot JAR. From there, you can open the resulting JAR and find the main class defined in the manifest, under `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. You'll see it under the `Start-Class` attribute:

```
Start-Class: com.example.foo.Application
```

Comment: My question was more of understanding the flow of the application than finding the main class. For example a Spring Boot webservice application the _@RestTemplate_ class could be the entry point, to understand where to begin understanding the code. One option could be separating configs in a separate class having _@Bean_ annotations, this would help in finding all bean wirings at one place. Is there a standard that large projects use to solve this code understanding problem?

Comment: @ManojMohandas If I understand your question, this process flow is managed by the programmer and can be controlled while designing.

Comment: @HimadriMandal - Is there a standard way of doing it? Like a good way to follow, that other big projects follow for the same? I am looking for something where a new developer just clones the project and spends some 1-2 days with no(or very limited) help in understanding the codebase.

Comment: I think the OP is studying an existing Spring Boot application, and is asking how to locate any runner, such as CommandLineRunner, MVC controllers, Rest controllers, etc. I don't know if there is an easy way to locate those, unless they are grouped together in the original design

Answer (score 0):

search @SpringBootApplication annotation in your project, the class with @SpringBootApplication annotation will automatically do the component-scan for the sub packages.

if no @SpringBootApplication annotation found, search the class extending  "SpringBootServletInitializer" which is also a starting point for the spring boot application

Comment: it is very well possible for several classes in a project to have that annotation

Answer (score 0):

The Entry of any spring boot application has an annotation of @SpringBootApplication